# How to list a list of classes in a listbox?

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I want to make a list with person's names, in a listbox. The names should be added using the textbox, and i am using a class for the name savement etc.

How can i show the name of the person that added info to a listbox, and only show the information to a richtextbox when the list is clicked/pressed?

class code

```
 class Persoon
{
    private string naam;
    private string geslacht;
    private double gewicht;
    private double lengte;
    public double bmi;


    public string Naam
    {
        get { return naam; }
        set { naam = value; }
    }
    public string Geslacht
    {
        get { return geslacht; }
        set { geslacht = value; }
    }
    public double Gewicht
    {
        get { return gewicht; }
        set { gewicht = value; }
    }
    public double Lengte
    {
        get { return lengte; }
        set { lengte = value; }
    }
    public double Bmi
    {
        get { return bmi; }
        set { bmi = value; }
    }

    public object Convert { get; internal set; }

    public Persoon(string nm, string gt, int wt, int le)
    {
        naam = nm;
        geslacht = gt;
        gewicht = wt;
        lengte = le;
    }

    public double BMI()
    {
        double bmiuitkomst = gewicht / Math.Pow(lengte / 100.0, 2);
        return bmiuitkomst;

    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Persoon: " + Naam + " " + Geslacht;
    }
```

form code

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string naam = tb_naam.Text;
        string geslacht = tb_geslacht.Text;
        double gewicht = Convert.ToDouble(tb_gewicht.Text);
        double lengte = Convert.ToDouble(tb_lengte.Text);
        double bmiuitkomst = gewicht / Math.Pow(lengte / 100.0, 2);



        Persoon nieuwbmi = new Persoon(naam, geslacht, Convert.ToInt32(gewicht), Convert.ToInt32(lengte));
        rtb_uitkomst.Text = "Naam: "+ naam + Environment.NewLine + "Geslacht: " + geslacht + Environment.NewLine + "BMI: " +   Convert.ToString(bmiuitkomst);
        // rtb_uitkomst.Text = nieuwbmi.ToString();

        List<string> uitkomsten = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in uitkomsten)

        {
            uitkomsten.Add(Convert.ToString(nieuwbmi));
        }
        // lb_list.(Convert.ToString(nieuwbmi));
        lb_list.DataSource = uitkomsten;
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: `List<string> uitkomsten = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in uitkomsten)

        {
            uitkomsten.Add(Convert.ToString(nieuwbmi));
        }` what is it for ? you create an empty list , then trying to loop

Comment: @Z.R.T. looking back at it, i have no idea what i was trying to do there. I want to create a list in the listbox showing the persons name, then when i click the name, the info of that specific person should  show up in the richtextbox.

Comment: @Z.R.T. Fixed it partly, the code now displays the name in the listbox, but also in the richtextbox. How can i make sure it only displays the info in the richtextbox when the name is selected (in the listbox)? Also, how can i add multiple lines to the listbox? Every new name should be added under the previously added name.

Comment: "How can i make sure it only displays the info in the richtextbox when the name is selected (in the listbox)"  control that behavior thought  SelectedIndexChanged event of listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a variable `uitkomsten` locally in `button1_Click`. This variable exists only while the method is executed. To make it live during the whole lifetime of the form, declare it as a field of the form class (and remove the declaration from the `button1_Click` method)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form

    private List<string> uitkomsten = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ...
}
```

---

Then you try to add a person with

```
foreach (var item in uitkomsten)
{
    uitkomsten.Add(Convert.ToString(nieuwbmi));
}
```

This cannot work. The `foreach` loop loops as many times as there are elements in the `uitkomsten` list. But since the list is empty at the beginning, the `Add` method will never be executed. Remove the loop.

```
uitkomsten.Add(Convert.ToString(nieuwbmi));
```

Note that you could add persons directly to the list, if you had a `List<Persoon>`. The listbox automatically uses `.ToString()` to display objects.

```
uitkomsten.Add(nieuwbmi);
```

---

Another problem is that `lb_list.DataSource = uitkomsten;` always assigns the same list. Because of how the listbox is implemented, it does not notice any difference and will therefore not display new persons added. To work around this problem, assign `null` first.

```
lb_list.DataSource = null;
lb_list.DataSource = uitkomsten;
```

Also change the weight and length parameters to `double` in the constructor of `Persoon`. You have doubles everywhere else for these measurements. If you use auto-implemented properties, this simplifies the class

```
class Persoon
{
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public string Geslacht { get; set; }
    public double Gewicht { get; set; }
    public double Lengte { get; set; }
    public double Bmi { get; set; }

    public Persoon(string nm, string gt, double wt, double le)
    {
        Naam = nm;
        Geslacht = gt;
        Gewicht = wt;
        Lengte = le;
    }

    public double BMI()
    {
        return Gewicht / Math.Pow(Lengte / 100.0, 2);

    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Persoon: {Naam} {Geslacht}";
    }
}
```

The form then becomes (with a few additional tweaks)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Persoon> uitkomsten = new List<Persoon>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string naam = tb_naam.Text;
        string geslacht = tb_geslacht.Text;
        double gewicht = Convert.ToDouble(tb_gewicht.Text);
        double lengte = Convert.ToDouble(tb_lengte.Text);

        Persoon nieuwbmi = new Persoon(naam, geslacht, gewicht, lengte);
        rtb_uitkomst.Text = $"Naam: {naam}\r\nGeslacht: {geslacht}\r\nBMI: {nieuwbmi.BMI()}";
        uitkomsten.Add(nieuwbmi);
        lb_list.DataSource = null;
        lb_list.DataSource = uitkomsten;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private List<string> uitkomsten = new List<string>();
    private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bs.DataSource = uitkomsten;
        lb_list.DataSource = bs;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ......
        uitkomsten.Add(Convert.ToString(nieuwbmi));
        bs.ResetBindings(false);
    }
```

How can i make sure it only displays the info in the richtextbox when the name is selected (in the listbox)?

```
    private void lb_list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Persoon nieuwbmi = ((Persoon)lb_list.SelectedItem).Name1;
        rtb_uitkomst.Text = "Naam: " + naam + Environment.NewLine + "Geslacht: " + geslacht + Environment.NewLine + "BMI: " + Convert.ToString(bmiuitkomst);
    }
```